# ajax request fail condition

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, http-status-code-404

I seem to be lost here. I have a jQuery request to send `GET` request with basic authentication. My problem is even if the authentication fails, the error code is never run. 
My request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(window.username + ":" + window.password));
    },
    success: callback,
    error:function(){
        console.log('ERROR: ' + jqXHR.status);
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log('VOTE: ' + jqXHR.status);
    }
});
```

I get error both in my JSON response and also in the `Status Code`. What am i doing wrong?

response body:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Authentication failed"
}
}
```

Response header:

```
Status Code: 401
Date: Wed, 29 Feb 2012 12:45:03 GMT
```

thanks in advance

Comment: what is the status code returned by the server

Comment: did you define jqXHR anywhere?

Comment: @Michel that's the same thing i thought

Comment: is the 'callback' function defined?

Comment: type: "GET", or "POST"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not defining the variables passed to the error function. Have you tried

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log('ERROR: ' + jqXHR.status);
    },
```

in your case i think it runs the error function but gives an error as  `jqXHR.status` is not defined

Comment: @Neelesh are you making a cross domain or jsonp request ? becuase in that case the error handler is not called

Comment: I am not making a cross domain request. The weird part is control does not go to any of the functions. Not even the success and the complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
function(){
    console.log('ERROR: ' + jqXHR.status);
}
```

is incorrect because the the variable jqXHR is not defined so you are getting a javascript exception in that line.

try

```
function(jqXHR){
    console.log('ERROR: ' + jqXHR.status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the error handler in a global to see if it makes a difference(with all the parameters):

```
jQuery(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, errorThrown) {
    var errorMessage = "Ajax error: " + ajaxSettings.url + " : " + errorThrown + " : " + jqXHR.statusText + " : " + jqXHR.status;

    if (jqXHR.status != "0" || errorThrown != "abort") {
        alert(errorMessage);
    }
});
```

EDIT NOTE: the parameters of the global vary slightly from the localized

```
 error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){},
```

and make the success explicit perhaps?

```
success: function(returnedStuff){
    callback(returnedStuff);
},
```